# page-router-outlet not working in my nativescript-ng2-magic project

Tags: android, angular, angular2-routing, nativescript

I want to create an app for both web and android using :
https://github.com/NathanWalker/nativescript-ng2-magic.
I have created 2 components HomePageComponent and AddPageComponent
but this code doesn't seem to work in my app.component.tns.html:

```
<page-router-outlet></page-router-outlet>
```

It should show me what's in my homepage.component.tns.html:

```
<ActionBar title="Home Page"></ActionBar>
```

here is the code in my app.routing.ts

```
import {HomePageComponent} from "./components/homepage/homepage.component";
import {AddPageComponent} from "./components/addpage/addpage.component";

export const AppRoutes: any= [
   {path:'', component: HomePageComponent},
   {path:'addpage', component: AddPageComponent}
];

export const AppComponents: any = [
   HomePageComponent,
   AddPageComponent
];
```

and the code of app.module.ts :

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { NgModule, NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA } from "@angular/core";
import { NativeScriptModule } from "nativescript-angular/platform";
import {AppRoutes, AppComponents} from "./app.routing";
import {NativeScriptRouterModule} from "nativescript-angular/router";
import {NativeScriptFormsModule} from "nativescript-angular/forms"

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent, ...AppComponents],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    NativeScriptModule,
      NativeScriptFormsModule,
      NativeScriptRouterModule,
      NativeScriptRouterModule.forRoot(AppRoutes)
  ],
  schemas: [NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is very important to wrap `<page-router-outlet></page-router-outlet>` with a layout container so try this:

```
<StackLayout>
  <page-router-outlet></page-router-outlet>
</StackLayout>
```

Also try adding this as well to your `HomeComponent` to see it:

```
<ActionBar title="Home Page"></ActionBar>
<StackLayout>
  <Label text="Home"></Label>
</StackLayout>
```

**EDITED 12/11/16:**

The order of your imports could be the culprit. You want the {N} platform import first; Also try using the `next` tag of `nativescript-angular` in your package (note with `next` tag, the import location changed to all import from same barrel), then clear node_modules, platforms again (`rm -rf node_modules platforms`) and reinstall. Plus you don't want to use the other angular imports so try updating to this:

```
import { 
  NativeScriptModule,
  NativeScriptFormsModule, 
  NativeScriptHttpModule, 
  NativeScriptRouterModule 
} from "nativescript-angular";
import { NgModule, NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA } from "@angular/core";
import { AppRoutes, AppComponents } from "./app.routing";
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent, ...AppComponents],
  imports: [
    NativeScriptModule,
    NativeScriptFormsModule,
    NativeScriptHttpModule,
    NativeScriptRouterModule.forRoot(AppRoutes)
  ],
  schemas: [NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: it didn't work unfortunately  :/ I already have an actionBar in my homepage Template the in the emulator it just shows me the default ActionBar with nativescript text in it

Comment: @HachimJ I updated the answer above regarding the order of your imports and to use the `next` tag, please give that a shot and let me know.